# Is there a way of implementing a bem sass library into a joomla project?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have been doing some research on the possibility of adding a sass bem library into a joomla project. I have not found something yet but not sure if this is possible.

I am also new to the joomla environment so I'm learning my way around it to implement a work environment I am comfortable with.

I have this [Sass Bem Library](https://github.com/danielguillan/bem-constructor) by Daniel Guillan I want to use together with [Joomla Gulp](https://github.com/phproberto/joomla-gulp)

Any Idea how I can implement this into a joomla project?

Comment: Does your server have a sass compiler already> if so then its just a simple matter of referencing the new library inside your main sass file.

Comment: Not yet. I am still setting up everything. I will basically just be using command line for installation of ruby and sass into my project together with the sass bem constructor library I want to use.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in adding the Sass, just drop it into your template and that's it.

The problem is then getting Joomla to spit out markup containing the css classes. To do that you will need to create template overrides for every view you are using, changing the standard Bootstrap classes for your own.

I use Sass in all my templates and have done for a long time. You might want to check out http://joomlafuture.com/ for an (outdated) example or https://joomlanauts.com/ for some newer implementations.